# Java uninstalling itself Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, java

I have two applications running with java (Java 1.7.0 upd 17 and Java 1.8.0 upd 25) on several clients. From yesterday to today I am receiving several tickets about Java being automatically uninstalled.

All customers who have reported are using Windows 7. All event logs show that uninstallation started from Windows by reconfiguring the Java Auto Updater.

Timeline:

> Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: Java Auto
>   Updater. Product Version: 2.8.25.18. Product Language: 1033.
>   Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Reset error or success status: 0.
>
> Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: Java 8
>   Update 25 (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.250. Product Language: 1033.
>   Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Reset error or success status: 0.
>
> Starting a Windows Installer transaction:
>   {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418025F0}. Customer Process ID: 1640.
>
> Product: Java 8 Update 25 (64-bit) - Removal completed successfully.
>
> Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: Java 8 Update 25
>   (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.250. Product Language: 1033.
>   Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Error or successful removal status:
>   0.
>
> Terminating a Windows Installer transaction:
>   {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86418025F0}. Customer Process ID: 1640.
>
> Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: Java SE
>   Development Kit 8 Update 25 (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.250.18.
>   Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Reset error
>   or success status: 0.
>
> Starting a Windows Installer transaction:
>   {64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0180250}. Customer Process ID: 1640.
>
> Product: Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 25 (64-bit) -- Removal
>   completed successfully.
>
> Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: Java SE
>   Development Kit 8 Update 25 (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.250.18.
>   Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Error or
>   successful removal status: 0.
>
> Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: Java SE
>   Development Kit 8 Update 25 (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.250.18.
>   Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. System
>   Reboot Type: 1. Reboot Reason: 1.
>
> Terminating a Windows Installer transaction:
>   {64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0180250}. Customer Process ID: 1640.
>
> Windows Installer has initiated a system reboot to complete or
>   continue the configuration of 'Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 25
>   (64-bit)'.

All these processes were executed by the user SYSTEM. Is anyone going through this too?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the auto-installer cannot continue in your environment after the boot

You need to turn off the auto-update of Java, and you will need to do the update
manually (if there is a real update to do).

I had a similar problem once and this was my solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you update to a newer version of Java, the Java installer notes the older version and uninstalls it.  You need to stop that during install. Also remember that older Java is insecure so I recommend only having the latest version

Comment: Does this happens by auto update too? Or has to be initiated by the user?

Comment: It needs to be initiated by the user.  Make sure Java is being used many of our users do not actually use Java

Comment: There is a Java update available today and I have just one version so the auto update is just simply updating

Comment: The application runs on a server that users usually do not have access to. All logs show that Windows has started uninstallation. There were many separate and independent servers that reported the same problem, some of them happened at dawn. There was no attempt to install another version of Java.

Comment: The reliability history on my machine shows 221 uninstalling and 231 installing. So unattended the automatic install leaves you with latest version